# What is a command-line equivalent of pressing a key on remote computer via ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, terminal, remote-desktop

What are the options to target specific keys on a remote computer and execute the equivalent of virtually pressing them from the terminal via ssh (what would normally be a user pressing them)?

Example is adjusting the volume:

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 10"
```

I'm not asking for applescript.

Answer (score 2):

There is some information about how to do that [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh). An excerpt from that page is included below.

> Terminals only understand characters, not keys. So al function keys
>   are encoded as sequences of characters, using control characters.
>   Apart from a few common ones that have an associated control character
>   (<kbd>Tab</kbd> is `Ctrl+I`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is `Ctrl+M`,
>   <kbd>Esc</kbd> is `Ctrl+[`), function keys send escape sequences,
>   beginning with `Ctrl+[ [` or `Ctrl+[ O`. You can use the
>   [`tput`](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora17/man1/tput.1.html)
>   command to see what escape sequence applications expect for each
>   function key on your terminal.

Also, [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) was suggested on the page linked above, if you are attempting to do the same sort of thing from an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands over ssh directly.
`ssh user@host1 command` will run the command on host1 under the user.
So to use your set volume example, you could do this -
`ssh root@host1 osascript -e "set Volume 10"`